# Won't load CSS structure when the link is correct, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

CSS doesn't load into HTML file. Attempted to load the allmight image and it didn't work, flexbox is also not loading.  Should I make it as an inline CSS, I would like to keep it seperate. Any some suggestions? Could I improve on the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/Flexbox.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flexbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="körper">
        <div id="anzeige">
            <div id="logosuche">
                <div id="logo">
                    <div id="symbol"></div>
                    <div id="name"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="suche">
                    <div id="g_logo"></div>
                    <div id="eingabefeld">
                        <input id="eingabe" type="text" value="Search with Google or enter address">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="icons">
                <div class="hover" id="umbruch1"><div class="icon"><img src="/Website_Images/allmight.png.png" alt="1" width="40px"><span>All Might</span></div></div>
                <div class="hover" id="umbruch2"><div class="icon"><img src="fortnite.png" alt="2" width="40px"><span>Donnerstag</span></div></div>
                <div class="hover" id="umbruch3"><div class="icon"><img src="fortnite.png" alt="3" width="40px"><span>Access</span></div></div>
                <div class="hover" id="umbruch4"><div class="icon"><img src="fortnite.png" alt="4" width="40px"><span>schmarn</span></div></div>
                <div class="hover" id="umbruch5"><div class="icon"><img src="fortnite.png" alt="5" width="40px"><span>i bin a bayer</span></div></div>
                <div class="hover" id="umbruch6"><div class="icon"><img src="fortnite.png" alt="6" width="40px"><span>pornos</span></div></div>
                <div class="hover" id="verschwinden1"><div class="icon"><img src="fortnite.png" alt="7" width="40px"><span>8 Euro</span></div></div>
                <div class="hover" id="verschwinden2"><div class="icon"><img src="fortnite.png" alt="8" width="40px"><span>spam</span></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file for reference, name of file is simply "Flexbox"

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    --background-color: rgb(229, 219, 246);
    --background-color-secondary: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    --text-primary-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

#körper {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: var(--background-color);
}

#anzeige {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#logosuche {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#symbol {
    height: 82px;
    width: 82px;
    background: url('logo.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size: 82px;
}

#name {
    height: 82px;
    width: 134px;
    background: url('name.svg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 134px;
    margin: 20px;
}

#suche {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 725px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#g_logo {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: url('g_logo.svg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#eingabefeld {
    height: 25px;
    width: 650px;
}

#eingabe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: grey;
}

#icons {
    display: flex;
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 25px);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hover {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 70px;
    height: 140px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.hover:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.icon {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 20px; 
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

img {
    margin: 20px;
}

input {
    outline: none;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    
    #suche {
        width: 625px;
    }

    #g_logo {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #eingabefeld {
        width: 550px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    
    #suche {
        width: 525px;
    }

    #g_logo {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    #eingabefeld {
        width: 450px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    
    #suche {
        width: 325px;
    }

    #g_logo {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #eingabefeld {
        width: 250px;
    }

}
```

Expected CSS file to cooperate and load structre with images and flexbox

Comment: Probably the link *isn't* correct. You think it is. How have you proven that? Have you checked the Network tab of your browser's developer tools and seen the 200 OK status with the CSS in the response body?

Comment: If the name of the file is **really** `Flexbox` without any ending, it's obvious that you cannot load it as `Flexbox.css`. with an ending

Comment: I think the href should be `href="./CSS/Flexbox.css"`

Comment: Please undelete your [recently deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77896804/i-keep-trying-to-run-a-couple-junit-tests-using-rest-and-springboot-and-my-tests) - it was about to be reopened (2 of 3 votes). (Ping me at @halfer when you have done so, I can give it a push).

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML file assumes the following directory structure:

```
index.html
CSS
 \_ Flexbox.css
Website_Images
 \_ allmight.png.png
```

with your HTML file the `CSS` folder and the `Website_Images` all inside the webroot of your webserver. If youre not using a server and open the html file directly, it will use the file system root (`/` on linux, probably `C:/` on windows)

Also make sure the file extensions are all correct, as Nico pointed out make sure the file is named "Flexbox.css" not "Flexbox" without file extension, also
"allmight.png.png" seems suspicious

Answer (score -2):

Check the file well before linking it to HTML.

If The "css" file is located in the same folder as the current page
Use this-: flexbox.css

If The "css" file is located in the images folder in the current folder.
Use this:-
Css/flexbox.css

If The "css" file is located in the images folder at the root of the current web.

Use this:- /css/flexbox.css

If The "css" file is located in the folder one level up from the current folder.
Use this:-   ..flexbox.css
I hope this might be able to help you out both on css files, js file and image. Thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).